# Conditionals and bisection search. (for python.)

Tags: python, conditional-statements, bisection

I'm a beginner in programming and I have a two basic question. The first concerns conditionals. If I have an `if` and `else` statement and the condition is met for the "if" statement, when it's finished with the `if`, the program will skip the `else` statement, right ? (Just to be sure.)

Second question concerns the use of bisection search. I went on Wikipedia and saw that it's main concern was with finding the zeros of polynomials. Well, if I'm not using it on polynomials, but to find the smallest sum of money to pay off a debt in a year with a minimal bound and maximal bound established (with interests,etc.)

The question is the following: Is the use of bisection search, in my context, only taking the average? Is there anything else than using an average? If this isn't clear, I'll give you the following link [Lecture 4: Machine Interpretation of a Program](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-1/lecture-4-machine-interpretation-of-a-program/MIT6_00SCS11_ps1.pdf).

Go see the problem number 3 and you'll understand better. If there's anything you need to know, tell me.

(By the way, I'm working with Python.)

Answer (score 1):

You should read the Python documentation. There's a very good tutorial included in it.

For your first question: yes, `else` only executes if the `if` condition was not met.

For the second question: that's more of a maths question than a programming question, and I'm not qualified to answer it, but I'd be willing to bet the problem asks you to use bisection search *because* it's not the same as just taking an average.

Comment: I assume English is not your native language? (I don't mean it as an insult.) I said, `else` *only* executes if the `if` condition was not met. That means if the `if` condition *is* met, `else` does not execute.

Comment: @Astroman Yes. Yes it skips the `else`. The `else` is skipped if the `if` is executed. If the `if` is executed, the `else` is skipped. If the `else` is executed, then the `if` was skipped. If the `if` is not executed, then the `else` is executed.